# Объясните, пожалуйста, что такое денотат, референт, сингнификат.

Tags: семантика

Только, пожалуйста, объясните своими слова и с примерами.

Comment: @tris, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Денотат - объект, обозначаемый каким-то именем. Класс объектов. Земляника – имя ягоды, формальная сторона знака, а представляем как предмет ягоду. Значит, денотат (предметная соотнесённость) – ягода, а название её земляника, а в других языках будет другое название. Анна Ивановна - мой учитель. Денотат - учитель.

Референт – то же самое – предмет, обозначаемый именем.

Сигнификат - понятийное (смысловое) СОДЕРЖАНИЕ единицы, которая заключает в себе характеризующую информацию об обозначаемом предмете. Т.е. это характеристика денотата (предмета), информация  о нём, то, как осмысливают этот предмет, выделяя его особенности, признаки.

В романе М. А. Булгакова «Мастер и Маргарита» сигнификативно (по смыслу) различные выражения гражданин, клетчатый, субъект, регент, переводчик, длинный клетчатый, неизвестный, клетчатый гаер, гад-переводчик, Коровьев, Фагот, надувало Фагот и т. п., но это одна личность, один денотат, мы представляем одно лицо, каждый раз по-новому, выделяя различные его признаки.